# First time travelling alone - transit Munich airport, terminal 2

Tags: airports, layovers, munich, lufthansa

I am 13 and it will be my first time travelling alone. I have a few questions related to my transit flight.
I am flying from Dublin->Munich->Sofia(Bulgaria) and I have my layover in Munich airport so:

1. What happens when you get off the plane would there be a like a special entrance door for transit passengers?
2. Will I have passport and security controls again?

The airline is Lufthansa.

Comment: What's your citizenship ?

Comment: @blackbird57 does it matter?

Comment: @phoog probably no you're right, force of habit I suppose !

Comment: Which airlines are you flying?

Comment: @neo Does *that* matter?

Comment: @phoog Yes, transiting between terminals 1 and 2 takes quite a bit of time and a not-so-frequent bus. A good answer should mention that. Also, the way to the other terminal is not signaged everywhere as far as I remember.

Comment: @neo fair enough. I've flown through Munich dozens of times but always on Lufthansa or a Lufthansa partner.

Comment: @neo: I have no clue why blackbird57 edited the question and removed that she is transiting in terminal 2, so both legs are probably Lufthansa or at least Star Alliance flights. I'll add that to the question again.

Comment: :D  both flights are Lufthansa and yes terminal 2 im trying to get more answers but ..

Comment: @phoog Knowing the citizenship would have enabled more specificity in the second paragraph of your answer #justsayin ;)

Comment: @TimMalone that's true, but the second paragraph of my answer is a bit of a digression.  The question doesn't actually ask about leaving the airport while waiting for the departing flight (and I suppose a 13-year-old will not likely want to do that, anyway).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're arriving from outside the Schengen area and going to a destination outside the Schengen area, yes, there will be a separate way for transit passengers. This is specifically so they can reach their outbound flights without passing through passport control.

If you are authorized, that is, if you have or do not need a visa to enter Germany, and if you have sufficient time, you can also pass through passport control and see the other parts of the airport or even go into the city.  If you do that, you'll also pass through exit passport control when you go to board your flight.

If you are worried about being confused by all of this, don't be. The signs are very easy to follow to get to the appropriate part of the airport.  To bypass passport control, follow the signs appropriate to your flight's gate number.

Comment: You can also ask anyone from the airline anytime, inside and outside the plane. They will be typically eager to help, and know all the details about where you can go and what you potentially need to do.