# Connecting from a Schengen inbound flight to a non-Schengen outbound flight at Munich airport

Tags: transit, canada, germany, international-travel, layovers

I'm 17 years old and I will be Flying on my own from Italy to Canada for the first time. I will travel from Italy to Munich and then I will take other flights. I will travel with Lufthansa for all the time and I don't have to change terminals. So, as I arrive at Munich Airport, do I have to follow the "connecting flight" sign? Then what should I do? 
Sorry, I'm a bit nervous.

Comment: Don't be nervous. I'm sure it will be fine. Does tour booking information or tickets tell you anything specifically?

Comment: Also, please can you edit your question title to something like 'How should I get to a connecting flight' or something with more detail than present? Thanks.

Comment: @NathanShoesmith you can (and are encouraged to) suggest an edit for that yourself (it even gives +2 rep),

Comment: Ok @mts - wasn't sure whether to change question names myself or request the op to change them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [First time travelling alone - transit Munich airport, terminal 2](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67511/first-time-travelling-alone-transit-munich-airport-terminal-2)

Comment: That's not exactly a dupe there as the other Q is from non-schengen to non-schengen whereas here you have to pass the Schengen border control so I did not vote to close

Answer (score 7):

Once your first flight lands, and you disembark and enter the airport, there will either be a sign, or an airport employee signalling which direction transit/onward/connecting passengers should go. Follow that and you should enter a part of a terminal where there are gates and one or more TV screens that show which flights correspond to which gates.

Look at your 2nd flight's flight number (either from ticket or boarding pass) and check the TV screens to know which gate your flight will be boarding from. Usually your flight will show up 2 hours before it departs, although some screens may show it even if there is more than 2 hours till it departs.

Once you know the gate number, follow the signs to the gate. Just ask any airport or airline employee if you need directions.

As you follow the signs, you'll be directed upstairs and come to a line and a series of booths for passport control. This is because your flight will be leaving the European Schengen area. Just wait in line until you reach an available booth and present your passport to the officer. There should be a special faster line available for EU citizens (there'll be a sign), which you could use if you're eligible, but someone will direct you if you go to the wrong place.

Once you get to the gate, have a seat and wait until they announce that it is time to board.

*Remember:* If you ever get lost, or confused, or if you can't find your flight number on the screens, do not hesitate to ask a member of airport staff. They may be tired and grumpy, but they will always help, no matter what. If they can't help, they will at least take you to someone who can.

Source: been traveling solo since age 16.

Comment: Good advice - glad somebody could post an answer

Comment: Connecting flights in MUC are announced way more than 2h in advance. OP will also have to go through pass control.

Comment: What do you mean pass control? (Not sure if you mean passenger or passport, either way I've never had that happen to me so could you elaborate what it entails?) And yeah, in my most recent trips at least one of the screens usually broadcasts gates before 2 hours, just threw that in there so he doesn't panic if he doesn't see it right away.

Comment: Small detail: EU citizens can use all lanes for the exit immigration check. Schengen countries are supposed to offer specific (faster) EU citizens lane at airports but EU citizens are explicitly allowed to go through the regular "all passports" lane if they want to.